# Using Mayan edms

Tags: python, rest, mayanedms

I want to use mayan edms as a storage backend for documents where I can retrieve documents based on 2 metadata keys. I know this is possible with the index capability, but I fail to understand how to do this in the rest api. 
So I need an example how to define an index and how to retrieve documents using this index with the rest-api.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create both indexes filtering rules to on your metadata keys:
https://docs.mayan-edms.com/chapters/indexes/examples.html#index-document-by-department-taken-from-the-first-character-of-the-invoice-number-metadata

example:

```
    {% if document.metadata_value_of.invoice_number.0 == "H" %}Human Resources
    {% endif %}
```

When this is working you can do a rest API call:

as example:
request.get('http://localhost/api/v4/index_instances/1/nodes/61/documents/')

https://docs.mayan-edms.com/chapters/rest_api.html#examples
together with the swagger `api/swagger/ui`/  and redoc `api/redoc/ui` and the django API `api/v4` in your Mayan EDMS installation website should help you in the right direction.